# How to Create a Process in Informatica Cloud Real time which gets exposed as Restful service and can be invoked from browser or else where?

Tags: web-services, informatica, informatica-cloud

Can we create a Webservice using Informatica?

I am very new to Informatica.

**Is the below requirement possible in using Informatica?**

My requirement is -

*"I want to **create** a Real Time **RESTful webservice** within Informatica Cloud which will fetch data from an Oracle Database and present output in JSON format when an particular URi is invoked."*

**Note:** I am not trying to connect to a Webservice, so please don't tell me about Webservice connector.

**I want to create a Webservice Server Provider within Informatica** so that when someone calls a URI in browser, this should query the Webservice deployed inside the Informatica Cloud and present the data on the browser in JSON format

**Edit: Re-framed the question in a more Informatica kinda language**

**Note:** If you provide step by step process I would really appreciate it.
I am a Java developer and I started learning Informatica like a week ago, I started from "What is Informatica?". So please explain as if you are explaining an idiot.

**Update ::** I have been using the following link as a reference. Using this as is doesn't work. I have been trying this for months now. I get an error while deploying. "Can't be deployed within tenant context" So definitely I am missing something. Can anybody throw some light on this please ?

http://www.onbostonharbor.com/Informatica/index.htm#page/bpm-na-process-developer/GUID-575B15AD-B21D-4979-9801-70564434FF2B.1.033.html

Comment: Something like this: https://community.informatica.com/solutions/mapping_webservices_provider ?

Comment: Not sure about Informatica cloud, however you can run a workflow as a web service in regular Informatica PowerCenter.

Comment: @JoachimRohde No Joachim, thanks for your inputs. Can you please atleast tell me if what I have asked is possible or not ?

Comment: Is there no one here who can help me ? I am in deep trouble.. :(

Comment: @JoachimRohde Any inputs on this ?

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot help you further on this.

Answer (score 0):

Oliver, is this still something you're trying to do?

In Informatica Cloud, you can define a JDBC connection to any JDBC-accessible database. To access the associated database via REST, there's an extra step on the connection definition where you specify that that you wish to OData-enable that particular connection. (OData being a particular REST specification.) You also have to specify which tables you'd like to expose. When you publish this connection, there will be a URL or service address that you can use to invoke this. You don't have to have this inside a full-blown process.

Then from within a browser or any HTTP-compatible client (Postman, for example), you are able to access any of the tables you've exposed using OData commands.

You can get some good background on OData at http://www.odata.org/getting-started/basic-tutorial/.

Hope this helps.